# Solutions for the equation $ \tbinom n3=m^2$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, diophantine-equations

From 'Proofs from the book', it stated that $ \tbinom n3=m^2$ has the unique solution n=50,m=140.
But how do we prove this is so?

Expansion of the equation above yields $n(n-1)(n-2)=6m^2$
which can be factorised into $(n-1)^3-(n-1)=6m^2$ which is a diophantine equation.
How do I prove that there are no other (positive) integer solutions for this equation?

Comment: Letting $x=n-1$, $y=m$, we rewrite this as $6y^2=x^3-x$ which is a well known type of diophantine equation called an elliptic curve. There are then certain methods that one can use to (try to) find all integer solutions, but the machinery used is very technical and I believe this comment is too small to contain it.

Comment: This seems to be related to [cannonball problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CannonballProblem.html). See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74265/one-sum-of-squares-and-two-diophantine-equations) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303778/techniques-to-prove-properties-of-a-sequence)

Comment: Also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345732/to-solve-nn1n2-6m3-in-positive-integers-m-n) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345739/to-find-positive-integers-n-such-that-dfrac-nn1n26-is-a-perfect-squ?lq=1) seem to by duplicates of this one.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the former question has the exponent of m set to 3 in the equation whilst the latter questions the possible solutions to the problem - of which the result of the book is referenced, but not the proof. (the book does not contain the proof of the result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p\neq 2,3$ a prime divisor of $m$. Since $p$ can divide only one of $n$, $n-1$ or $n-2$, we conclude that, apart from square factors, the  only possibilities for $(n,n-1,n-2)$ are:
$$(6,1,1);(2,3,1);(2,1,3);(3,2,1);(1,2,3);(1,6,1);(3,1,2);(1,3,2);(1,1,6)$$ 
It`s simply to exclude (6,1,1) and (1,1,6), cause you can't have two consecutive square.
In the case (2,3,1) you should have, in particular, the relation $a^2+1=3b^2$, and by standard theory on pell equation you know that there are no solution.
In a similar way you exclude the cases (3,1,2) (1,2,3) and (1,6,1).
Now consider the case (2,1,3). This is equivalent to the following system of pell equations:
$$\begin{cases}
b^2-3a^2=1\\
b^2-2c^2=-1
\end{cases}$$
Using again the theory on pell equation you can find the family of solution $(b_k,a_k)$ and $(b_k,c_k)$ for the two equations, and you search for a match of the $b_k$ of the two family. Since one of the sequence grows exponentially faster than the other, it suffices to verify just a few $k$. You find the only solution $a_k=4, b_k=7, c_k=5$, that corresponds to the triple $(50,49,48)$.
In the case $(1,3,2)$ and $(3,2,1)$ you proceed in the same way and you find that there are no other solutions.

Comment: Thanks! How about the cases (1,2,3), (3,2,1), (1,6,1) then?

Comment: I forgot them, sorry. I've edited to include the missing cases (the arguments are the same).

Comment: I don't understand the part on "since one sequence grows exponentially faster than the other, it suffices just to verify a few k". Aren't we just comparing the 'b' term in each element of each sequence with all other 'b' in the other?

Comment: Yes, but  the corresponding $a$ and $c$ can't be much different. That's the point that allows you to verify just a finite numbers ot term. It's quite tedious to fix all deltails, but i think this is the simplest way you can deal with the problem.